# How to set registry mirror for docker toolbox in windows

Tags: docker

I found a file called `com.docker.service.config` under `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker`. How to configure the registry mirror inside this file? The file is in XML format as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Can't find any documentation on docker official website, can anyone shed some light? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution unintentionally:

Open `C:\Users\<YourName>\.docker\daemon.json`, edit the "registry-mirrors" entry in that file.

[image]

```js
{"registry-mirrors":["https://registry.docker-cn.com"],"insecure-registries":[], "debug":true, "experimental": true}
```

Comment: It seems I do not have a file daemon.json on my side. I created one with the snippet you provided but it does not seem enough. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Update: I found a config file under `C:\Users\<user>\.docker\machine\machines\default` it contains a line which I updated as follow `"RegistryMirror": ["https://registry.docker-cn.com"],` but when I pull an image it stills pull from `Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/`

Comment: @Alexis.Rolland, have you tried restart after your edit?

Comment: @JeffTian I figured out your answer about the file `deamon.json` is for Docker Desktop (Windows Pro), not Docker Toolbox (Windows Home)

Comment: what about docker toolbox for windows 8 ? where to locate daemon.json?

Answer (score 2):

```
docker-machine ssh default
sudo sed -i "s|EXTRA_ARGS='|EXTRA_ARGS='--registry-mirror=https://registry.docker-cn.com |g" /var/lib/boot2docker/profile
exit
docker-machine restart default
```

See [this](http://guide.daocloud.io/dcs/daocloud-9153151.html#docker-toolbox).

Answer (score 1):

You can also add registry-mirrors property by going to `settings > Docker Engine` inside Docker Desktop application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For windows version not equal to 10, if you are using docker toolbox, you can find the daemon settings under: C:\Users[username].docker\machine\machines\default\config.json but the settings names differ slightly from daemon.json windows 10.